# Broadcast Android

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to build more Android app that can send data of another Android app. 
Now there are for example 3 apps (OneApp, TwoApp, ThreeApp) and another app (AlertAPp).

Now I want the the 3 apps can send soma data at AlertApp and in the future, another app can send data at AlertApp never change other apps code.

I have see the Broadcast receiver in Android but I don't know if it is the good solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data through intents

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent); // or startActivityForResult
```

More details on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send).

Also you can use a public database (not saved in cache), but encrypted, or files.

Comment: Catalin, thanks for your answer. I suppose that OneApp send this message. How can Alert App intercept this message ?

Comment: @bircastri using intents, you could start your wanted app, in your case `Alert App` by knowing your app package and class that should receive data

Comment: Ok thanks, but I can for example send the message from an app to another app, and the second one works in background ?

Comment: Yes. This approach is similar how you send and email using intents.

Answer (score 0):

> first app from what you want to send broadcast

`sendBroadcast(new Intent("KEY_STRING_ANYTHING")
                               .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES)
                               .setComponent(new ComponentName("APP_PACKAGE_NAME", "APP_PACKAGE_NAME.receiver.MyBroadcastReceiver")));`

> second app from what you want to receive a broadcast, In manifest Application Tag - declare the receiver of MyBroadcastReceiver (also enable this 2 properties - android:enabled="true"
>               android:exported="true") and inside that declare intent-filter as below

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="KEY_STRING_ANYTHING" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

> receiver/MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("data", intent.getAction());
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Const.EventBroadcast);
    intent1.putExtra("action", intent.getAction());
   *compare key and perform action*}
```